# Advice on pursuing a PhD

Tags: phd

Before diving into the question I'll just give some necessary background:

I have just finished a master's degree in electronic engineering with a top grade (First Class Honours) from a reputable university in Ireland. Originally when I started the bachelor's degree my goal was to become a circuit designer but as time went on I naturally focussed more and more on "pure" mathematics (e.g. Signal Processing, Machine Learning, Linear Algebra, Data Structure & Algorithms, Graph Theory etc...).

I did work placement working as a software engineer and I really enjoyed it. When I came back to university for my master's I focussed on Deep Learning and did quite a good dissertation/thesis which is either very close to publishable or publishable.

I accepted a position as a software engineer at the company which I did my work placement which I am excited to start with and it will be good experience but every time I hear about some of the cool research areas nowadays it makes me completely rethink my decision and I go into a frenzy worrying about whether I should have done a PhD in x or y etc. For example the reason I am writing this is because today I went down the rabbit hole of whether or not to do a PhD in quantum computing (more the algorithm side of things) and I have a list of about 60 different ideas of things I want to do/research like "Quantum computers for neural network execution" etc...etc.

In summary I'm really struggling to come to terms with my decision, I took the job for two reasons, I enjoyed the work and my supervisor who I could learn a lot from and the fact that the money will really help give me some independence like moving out of home. I have signed the contract so that is going ahead regardless but I think what I really need in the short-term is to know that I have the option to something like this later if I really feel the calling to it. With the background that I have given, is it not ridiculous for me to assume that I would be a competitive candidate for a PhD/Research position in the areas of Machine Learning or Quantum Computing (Algorithms, Software Tools that side of quantum computing) ?

Apologies if this is the wrong place to post this, I kind of just couldn't take second guessing myself anymore.

Comment: what is the view of your company in supporting you towards a PhD? ask your line manager if it would be a suitable goal for "long term skills improvement"?
If you have 60 topics, there must be 1 that shows some promising for-profit application in 5 years (i.e. you can do your PhD in peace while the management is company because they will have a market advantage towards the end of your phd)...

Comment: @EarlGrey They do fund PhDs but mostly in the area of Analog Circuit Design. That is a possibility I'll look into while I'm there but most of 60ish topics are just ideas I'd like to delve into in the area of machine learning and quantum computing.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from looking for a PhD now, in your free time. Some people find stimulating to use their holidays to booze in the sun, some others find stimulating to use their holidays to apply and to read books/paper/write proposals. Neither is right or wrong, but do what is interesting for you.  Apply for PhD positions, get feedbacks. You will see how real are your chance and motivations. Out of 60 ideas you will find open positions related to them, apply to them and keep in mind that **even when stated otherwise**, PhD positions do not require previous solid experience in anything.

Comment: @EarlGrey Thanks that's quite useful. I actually have about 2 months this summer scheduled off to research these areas so hopefully that'll help. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody is going to be able to tell you if you made the right decision for your particular situation.

Making decisions like this one is difficult.  I find a framework to help you organize is of value.  I recommend [Lakein, How to Get Control of Your Time and Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0451167724) as a valuable tool.

Lakein recommends spending time figuring out what your long-range plans are.  Do you value wealth, fame, beneficence, early retirement, love, ...?  Write it down.

Then, start with shorter term plans for how you plan to reach the big-picture goals you just generated.  Keep writing shorter term plans, until you're working on your daily to-do lists.  Constantly review those lists, and if you don't understand how a list item will help you reach your long-term goals, you might consider why that item is on your short-term list.

Now, that said, there are probably more pleasant ways to spend your time than pursuing a PhD.  It shouldn't be taken on lightly.  Given the above exercises, if a PhD seems to be the only way to reach your long-term goals, you should strongly consider changing your immediate plans, or find a way to work the PhD in to your current plan.

I sit every student who asks me for a recommendation down, and ask them to tell me why a PhD is necessary for them to reach their goals.

AS with any such tool, this is just a tool, and may or may not push you to the correct path.  Take it for what it's worth.  In engineering design, we use many such tools to screen ideas and land on the right design solution.  When they point us to an answer we know is incorrect, it often means there's something yet to be worked out in our process that we haven't considered important enough to write down that merits more consideration -- but anything that helps you think about your issue in an organized way is often a plus and not a minus.